# How can I wrap this as a helper function?

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8

Assume I am having such code snippets:

```
try {
   // code I need to wrap to be a helper
   long t0 = System.nanoTime();
   obj.doSomething();   // a void function
   long t1 = System.nanoTime();
   Logger.info("doSomthing takes {} nanoseconds", t1-t0);
}  catch (IOException ex) {
   Logger.error("something wrong happened");
}



// another code 

try {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    obj.doAnotherThing();   // void function 
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Logger.info("doSomthing takes {} nanoseconds", t1-t0);
}  catch (IOException ex) {
   Logger.error("something wrong happened");
}
```

So my question is actually how I can pass that void function as a parameter to a helper function, so that  I can avoid redundant code for measuring the execution time of the function.

---

**Follow Up: what if doSomething can throw IOException**

In this case how should I invoke the function in the lambda world if I don't want to catch the exception in labmda.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to use lambdas, since you tagged them? That would be what to try.

Comment: Look at the `Runnable` functional interface.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `Runnable`:

```
public void timeThis(Runnable runnable) {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    runnable.run();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Logger.info("Execution took {} nanoseconds", t1 - t0);
}
```

You can then pass the function you want to run as an argument to `timeThis`:

```
timeThis(() -> obj.doSomething());
```

If `obj.doSomething()` happens to throw an `IOException` like you mentioned below, you can simply catch it within the body of the `Runnable`:

```
timeThis(() -> {
    try {
        obj.doSomething();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

**Note**: This is not a proper benchmark.  See: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: or `timeThis(obj::doSomething);`

Comment: Just got a follow up question, what if doSomthing will throw IOException, how can I use this timeThis helper?

Answer (score 0):

Though you got a relevant answer yet for exception handling part, I would recommend using `JOOL` library from `JOOQ`. It provides a handy set of `FunctionaInterface` up to 16 parameters. **It also provides `CheckedRunnable` which allows the checked and unchecked exceptions to be thrown out of run method which could be handled as per your requirement.**

So,

```
public void timeThis(Runnable runnable) {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    runnable.run();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Logger.info("Execution took {} nanoseconds", t1 - t0);
}
```

will become:-

```
public void timeThis(CheckedRunnable runnable) {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    runnable.run();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    Logger.info("Execution took {} nanoseconds", t1 - t0);
}
```

And now you use it like below:-

```
try {
    timeThis(() -> {
        obj.doSomething();
   });
  } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Observe that you don't have to handle the exception twice as are able to throw exception outside the lambda expression.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

Try using Java Reflection methods. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html
The wrapper function can take Method as input wherein Method value is initialized in caller. Within wrapper function use invoke to call the passed method.

Comment: Using reflection for this is bad software design.